# unaccessible QString in constructor

Tags: c++, qt, subclass, qobject

I kind of messed up with subclassing in a big project. I realised the problem was somewhere in the subclassing process, resulting in **unaccessible `QString in`** in the constructor of `Subclass1`.

Why can't I access QString in if I set a breakpoiont at `test = in;`?

Windows 7 64bit, Qt 5.6.2, MinGW 4.9.2

(Probably just some careless mistake)

**Update1:** Fun part now, in is also not accessible in constructor of superclass, but is valid in `second(in)`.

**Update2:** Added images

main.h

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <QObject>

class Superclass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Superclass(QString in, QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent), second(in)
    {
        QString test = in;
    }
protected:
    QString second;
};

class Subclass1 : public Superclass
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Subclass1(QString in, QObject *parent = 0) : Superclass(in, parent)
    {
        test = in;
    }

protected:
    QString test;
};

class Manager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Manager(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
    {
    }

public slots:
    void runinvoked()
    {
        ptr1 = new Subclass1("test",this);
    }

    void rundirect()
    {
        ptr2 = new Subclass1("test",this);
    }

protected:
    Superclass *ptr1;
    Superclass *ptr2;
};

#endif // MAIN_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Manager *m = new Manager();
    m->rundirect();
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m,"runinvoked");
    return a.exec();
}
```

Superclass w/ empty `QString in`, correctly assigned `QString second`
[image]

Subclass w/ unaccessible `QString in`
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `in` being `inaccessible`?

Comment: It may be a display bug, since I can access the values after. Doing this in the big application results in a crash though... The debugger shows the same behaviour on accessing the values though.

Comment: Ah - you can't inspect the value of `test` when you have a breakpoint in the line `text = in;`? That's probably because the debugger holds *before* the line is executed. Second to that: Why don't you use the initializer-list for initializing `test` like this: `Subclass1(QString in, QObject *parent = 0) : Superclass(in, parent), test(in) {}`

Comment: I do not want to access `test`, I want to access `in`.

Comment: Yeah, could be some optimization due to debugger. If you want to have a check could be useful _qDebug()_

Comment: OT: Use `QScopedPointer<>` or `QSharedPointer<>` for `ptr1` and `ptr2` to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: This is a minimal example, the real application is about 800k lines of code and has shared/scoped pointers, a lot of debugging/logging facilities etc.

Comment: I am with Andy on this most probably being a compiler optimization. I would log `in` after you assign it to `test` in both cases to avoid it being optimized away. Or maybe you want to compile with `-O0`.

Comment: It is compiled w/ -O0